# Lp spaces are nested but then why is 1/x square summable but not summable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

If $1\leq s<r<\infty$ and $f\in L^r$ then $f\in L^s$, so then why is $\frac{1}{x}$ not in $L^1$ but is in $L^2$ for the counting measure $c:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It requires that the measure space be finite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$L^p$ spaces are not always nested. Let$M=\sup\{\mu(E)|\mu(E)\neq\infty\}$ and $m=\inf\{\mu(E)|\mu(E)\neq0\}$.

If $s<r$, and $M<\infty$, then $L^r\subseteq L^s$. If $m>0$, then the reverse holds.